# What does "undefined" in the outputs mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the Node interpreter:

```
> 1+3
4
> var name=12
undefined
> console.log(typeof name)
number
undefined
```

What does `undefined` in the outputs mean?

Why doesn't `1 + 3` output `undefined`, while the other two do?

Comment: That is the return value.

Comment: because of the return, 1+3 has an int return type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `1 + 3` returns `4`. A variable declaration doesn't return anything, and neither does `console.log`. The value you're seeing as `undefined` is the return value. Variable assignments, however (`var hello; hello = "hello"`) does return the value assigned (thanks VLAZ for pointing that out).

Comment: "*A variable assignment doesn't return anything,*" correction a variable *declaration* (using `var`, `let`, or `const`) doesn't return anything but assignment always returns the value assigned - `console.log(name = "hello")` will print `"hello"` and also set the value of `name`. More broadly, it's because the declaration is *a statement*, while assignment is *an expression*. Statements don't return a value, expressions can.

Comment: Whoops, my bad @VLAZ.

Answer (score 1):

You are using node REPL ([moreinfo)](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl)

REPL stands for Read-Eval-Print-Loop.
As the name says it will read you input, evaluate it (run it) print the result and repeat.
The print part will print whatever your code return. So what it is doing is something like this:

```
console.log(eval({your expression here}))
```

So applying to your cases we have:

```
console.log(1+3) // 4
console.log(var name=12) // undefined because an attribution doesn't return anything
console.log(console.log(typeof name)) // first the inner console.log will print the type of name (number) and then the outer console.log will print undefied (the return of the inner console.log).
```

Hope it's clearer like this.